# Arch Linux Live CD Fails to boot on Dell PowerEdge

Tags: linux, boot, raid, freeze, arch-linux

one of my friends is trying to run a Minecraft server off of his old Dell PowerEdge server and wanted to get rid of Windows Server 2003 in favor of Arch Linux.

After he burned a CD he was able to get to the initial menu.  After clicking the button  the button to boot the 32-bit version of Arch it initially runs well, but it always freezes after displaying a message about treating sda as a write cache.  I don't believe this is a fatal error as I have the same message appear on my laptop.  In addition, it displays a message about a problem with the timer which when researched I learned that it concerns a bug in the BIOS which the kernel had to work around.  my first thought was that ACPI may have been the problem (it has been in the past) so I had him boot the cd with the acpi=off kernel parameter, but to no avail.

One of my thoughts now is that this could possibly be caused by the RAID array in his machine. if so, is there any way for me to make the kernel ignore it until I configure it correctly?  I'm not home at the moment so I can't Skype him to get a screenshot of the point where it freezes but I'll get that information as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the CD to boot on other computers?

Comment: I have, it worked in his laptop.

Comment: Have you seen this https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1163823? It is an installation problem on a DelL Power Edge with RAID. Perhaps you should check it out.

Comment: That looks really useful! I'll be sure to check it out and see where it takes me.

Comment: Ok, so I had him try that.  Now he gets stuck at "Triggering uevents...".  This occurs whether or not RAID is enabled.

Comment: @Petrusd987, have you found a solution? I'm getting the same problem, but with a different hardware